# How To Set Gateway, DNS server Address On Lone PC with IP Cam?

Tags: ip, ethernet, gateway

If I set my ethernet adapter to a different subnet in order to connect with an IP cam on that net what Gateway Address and DNS server addresses should I use?

Currently I leave them blank and things seem to work alright but I'd like to know a little more about it all.

Am I clear enough?  The PC is usually wifi connected to a router. The onboard ethernet adapter is usually disabled.

I disable the wifi adapter and connect the IP cam to the ethernet adapter and enable the ethernet adapter.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the gateway and dns as you are connecting straight to a device and not via a router, and have no need for any routing.